# What Bracha to say when there is no clear majority?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, mezonot-beracha

I know that the Bracha for a mixture dish would go by the main component which in turn is determined by the majority.

E.g. for rice with some peas the blessing is Mezonot.

My question is what if there is no clear majority - what if the rice is 40% and there is 30% peas and 30% carrots? in this case the largest component is the rice but on the other hand there is 60% combined of components that bears the Bracha "Pri HaAdama"? is the rice still considered the main component?

Comment: Note some say Haadama on rice too.

Comment: @DoubleAA the Baal HaTanya brings up that some opinions hold aroz talked about in the talmud may not be rice and might either be shehakol or haadama. He therefore suggests to wash and eat bread when eating rice which would satisfy all opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a good question and in fact it is answered only by reading between the lines.

The Halachic terms are Ikkar ("main component" in the question) and Taffel (a lesser component).

From the Shulchan Aruch (Siman 212), the Achronim have concluded that the Taffel actually does require a Beracha but that it is included in the Beracha of the Ikkar. The evidence for that claim is that the Shulchan Aruch says that if you eat the Taffel before the Ikkar you actually have to bless it's Beracha (and later of course you also have to bless on the Ikker it's Bracha).

From that observation Achronim have concluded that the blessing determines the Ikker. So, to answer your question, **you would bless on the carrot and pees** (Boire Pri HaAdama) and the rice will not require it's own Beracha.

An interesting complication (to which I don't know the answer) would be if 3 components are present, each with a different blessing and none is over 50%...

Another note is that if you want to comply with the rule of the Chayei Adam who thinks that you should bless for each component if it is distinguishable (Nickar) then you should  squash the dish and then make the (one) proper blessing (you cannot bless for each of the components because we fear the Issur of "[Bal Tosif](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%A2)").

Note also the exception that if the smaller component is of the "[5 grain types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chametz#The_five_grains)" (חמשת מיני דגן), even so, it is considered Ikkar (and will cause the suiting Beracha, which is Mezonot)  providing that it gives its taste to the dish  (as opposed to cases where it is just "a glue" for the other components etc).

*Bon appetit*

Comment: "carrot and pees" - I think that's a different bracha :)

Answer (score 0):

The website [jewish pathways](http://www.jewishpathways.com/files/Special_Status_of_Mezonot.pdf) seems to discuss this very issue and concludes based on the Mishna Berurah and the Schulhan Aruch that that ikkar v'taffel is handled differently with mezonot food:

> Rule #1 – A mezonot food receives its own bracha even when it is the tafel. [MB 208:23]
>   Rule #2 – When mixed with other ingredients and made into one food, a mezonot ingredient is always considered the ikar, even though it is not the majority. [OC 208:2]

There are exceptions cited in the source, but since those exceptions pertain to situations that the mezonot is "solely an accompaniment", such as breadcrumb coatings, or when your intention is to eat it solely to make the ikkar "palatable [Brechot 44a]" it would not seem to apply to the situation in question.

To summarize: given the two rules above: the rice would be always be considered the ikar even tough it might not be the majority component.

Comment: This is actually not correct: The idea of "ikkar v'taffel is handled differently with mezonot food" is only in cases where the Mezonos is for the 5 grains and not for rice.